# getting variable name in file name for bash

Tags: bash

I wanted to change the name of my file from file.txt to file_4i.txt and file_5i.txt according to the number I need but when I use the command below, the file name changes to file_.txt and the value of m never is indicated. I wanted to get 4i but $mi does not work either.

```
sudo sh -c "m=4 ; mv file.txt file_$mi.txt"
sudo sh -c "m=4 ; mv file.txt file_$m.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes so the variable doesn't expand early, and use `{}` so `mi` isn't interpreted as the variable name:

```
sudo sh -c 'm=4 ; mv file.txt file_${m}i.txt'
sudo sh -c 'm=4 ; mv file.txt file_$m.txt'
```

Comment: I get file_{4}i.txt  not file_4i.txt by using your answer.

Comment: @vkaul11 It works when I try it. What is sh on your system? For me, it's dash version 0.5.8-2.1ubuntu2.

Comment: @vkaul11 Also, are you sure you did `${m}` and not `{$m}`?

Comment: `${m}` should work in any Bourne-style shell, that syntax has been around for ages.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I was just confused about single quotes vs double quotes as I thought double quotes are needed to interpret variables.

Comment: @vkaul11 They are, but you don't want the variable to be interpreted at first, since m isn't set until after that step.